# Restricted search on a list to hide private column

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, search, custom-list, search-scope

We have a list called employee. Out of all columns search result should not show 2 private columns named DOB & salary. Result can show all other columns.

I mean how to implement restricted search on this employee column?

Pl suggest.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This page should point you in the right direction: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointsearch/thread/2f56b352-33eb-42ac-a814-ee04f5194878

How are you preventing these two "private" columns from appearing in the UI?